# Is it possible to pass an exception to a handler and then rethrow the original exception?

Tags: c++, exception

I am trying to write code which is passed a handler for when errors occur.

```
class Handler {
   public: virtual void handle(std::exception const& e) = 0;
};

class DoIt {
  Handler* handler;
  public:
  void doStuff() {
    try {
      methodThatMightThrow();
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
      handler->handle(e);
    }
  }
  void setHandler(Handler* h) { handler = h; }
  void methodThatMightThrow();
```

}

Different projects will use this class with different error handling techniques.

Project 1 logs an error

```
class Handler1: public Handler {
  void handle(std::exception const& e) override {
    logError(e.what());
  }
};
```

Project 2 propagates the exception

```
class Handler2: public Handler {
  void handle(std::exception const& e) override {
    throw e;
  }
};
```

Both of those should work.  However, `Handler2` will throw a copy of the exception and lose any derived class information if the exception is a subclass of `std::exception`, which it almost certainly is.

Is there a good way to rethrow the original exception, or even a copy of the same type?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the naked `throw` to rethrow the current exception.

Rewriting your `Handler2` to use this would give the following code:

```cpp
class Handler2 : public Handler
{
public: void handle(const std::exception& ex) const override
    {
        throw;
    }
};
```

You don't have to send in the exception as an argument, and could write more advanced handlers which could do different things depending on the type of exception such as this simple handler.

```cpp
class WrapperHandler : public Handler
{
public:
    void handle() const
    {
        try
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (const notveryserious_exception& ax)
        {
            std::cout << "Not very serious, I'm going to let this slide." << std::endl;
            std::cout << ax.what() << std::endl;
        }
        catch (const myown_exception& ax)
        {
            // Probably serious, will let this propagate up the stack.
            throw;
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            // Bad, bad, bad.. Unhandled exception that we haven't thrown ourselves.
            throw myown_exception("Unhandled exception.");
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't throw a reference. Throw needs a real copy of the object. The copy is slicing the reference to the type at the point of the throw.

I'm not aware of a workaround to this problem.

Comment: It could throw dynamically allocated exception objects. The catch is then for pointer to exception. This would solve the slicing problem.